# Jmeter csv config for file upload

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, load-testing

I'm using Jmeter for testing file uploads.    This works great when I upload just one file,  but I want to be able to loop through a list of files.  I see Jmeter has a CSV based config capability,  but I can't figure out how to include a file as one of the params.

How can I specify a list of different files for jmeter to loop through,  uploading one per request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass:

- either relative or full path to the file being uploaded
- upload input name
- file MIME type

So if your CSV file will look like:

```
c:/testfiles/test.txt,upload,text/plain
c:/testfiles/test.jpg,upload,image/jpeg
etc.
```

And CSV Data Set Config is configured as:

[image: CSV Data Set]

Your HTTP Request Sampler configuration should look somehow like

[image: HTTP Request Sampler]

References:

- [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
- [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter)